# function defined on set of either finite or complementary finite subsets of infinitely coutable universal set

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, functions, set-theory

> Let $X:=\{x_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ and let $F:=\{A\subseteq X|\text{ $A$ is finite } \lor\text{ $A'$ is finite } \}$; define a function $\mu:F\mapsto [0,\infty)$ a such that

$\mu:=\begin{cases} 0 \text{ | $A$ is finite } \\ 1 \text{ | $A'$ is finite } \end{cases}$

> Prove that $\mu$ is finitely additive.

So, far, this is what I've written down; I need help with the part in which some sets are finite and others have a finite complement.

Let $\{A_k\}_{k=1}^n\subseteq F$, all of them mutually disjoint.

Consider the case in which $\forall_{k|k=1,...,n}[A_k \text{ is finite } ]$, then one'd also have $\forall_{k|k=1,...,n}[\mu(A_k) = 0 ]$ and, thus, $\Sigma_{k=1}^n\mu(A_k) = 0$.
On the other hand $\dot\bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k$ is finite, since it's a finite union of finite sets, which implies $\mu(\dot\bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k)=0$.

Now consider the case in which $\exists_{k|k=1,...,n}[A'_k\text{ is finite }]$. Suppose $\{A_i\}_{k=q}^m\subseteq\{A_i\}_{k=1}^n$ such that $A'_i$ is finite (and $1\leq m\leq q\leq n$), then one'd have $\Sigma_{k=1}^n\mu(A_k) = q-m+1$...

"$\square$"

This is as far as I have come, i don't know how to handle the big union of all $A_k$ and separate finites from complementary finites, I don't even know if I'm taking the right approach.

Any ideas, hints, whatever, on what to do here? I'm stuck. (If it's of any use, $F$ is the algebra of sets generated by the set $\{\{x\}|x \in X\}$)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(A_k)_{k=1}^n\subseteq F$ all of them mutually disjoint.

Lemma: There can be at most one $A_i$ so that $A_i'$ is finite.

Proof: Otherwise, we can assume without loss of generality that $A_1'$ and $A_2'$ are finite. But then $(A_1 \cap A_2)' = A'_1\cup A'_2$ is finite, which implies that $A_1\cap A_2$ is non-empty. That's a contradiction as we assumed that the $A_i$'s are mutually disjoint.

You already established the case where all of the sets are finite, so it suffices to study the case where one of the sets has $\mu(A_{i_0})=1$.

In that case $(\bigcup_i A_i)' = \bigcap_{i=1}^\infty A'_i \subseteq A_{i_0}'$ is finite. and therefore
$\mu(\bigcup_i A_i) =1$

On the other hand $\sum_{i=1}^n \mu(A_i) = \mu(A_{i_0}) =1$.